# Joomla Virtuemart special kind of coupon

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart, coupon

I want to create a special kind of coupon that works for the User only if he buys Products from a specific Manufacturer: is that possible? 
Straight or even working around it? 
Or do you know any extension that can make it done? 
Thanks

Comment: http://forum.virtuemart.net/

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [awocoupon](http://awodev.com/products/joomla/awocoupon).  It comes with alot of features that are missing from Virtuemart coupon system.